# How can I use environment variables in node-sass .scss files?

Tags: create-react-app, node-sass

I want a configurable default color variable maintained in an .env file. For example I would want an .env file that contains

```
PRIMARY=red
```

And a `_variables.scss` file that contains

```
$primary: ${process.env.PRIMARY}
```

And an SCSS file that contains

```
.my-class { color: $primary; }
```

And components where I use the stylesheets that contains

```
import './MyComponent.scss';
```

Is this possible? If not, what alternatives would I have?

- node v12.13.1
- node-sass v4.13.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using webpack and sass-loader (you will need to eject, which I think is worth it if you don't mind extra files and more dependency updating), modify your webpack.config.js file like this:

```js
const { castToSass } = require('node-sass-utils');

module.exports = {
...
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "style-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "css-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader"
        options: {
          functions: {
            "env($variable)": variable => castToSass(process.env[variable]);
          }
        }
    }]
  }
```

Now you could make a file `_variables.scss` like this:

```
$primary: env('primary');
```

If this doesn't work or you need more flexibility, check out the [article I based it off of](https://itnext.io/sharing-variables-between-js-and-sass-using-webpack-sass-loader-713f51fa7fa0) and feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Hmh, damn. Thanks. I was afraid of something like this. I might have even stumbled on your article when researching. I've never done any of that before and tbh it looks very daunting. I'm using create-react-app and node-sass and it just works, I didn't have to configure anything.

Comment: @Nenotlep I agree, this is probably not something you want to do. If possible, you should put colors in your _variables.scss rather than in environment variables, I just don't understand why you would use environment variables at all.

Comment: The need is provide customer-specific view customizations. My app is one that our customers reveal to their customers; they need to use their company colors and logos.

So I would have lets say 20 different production envs all with different, custom, color schemes and I would want that to be configured in ENV rather than trying to remember to change it before a build. Makes sense?

Comment: If you happen to be using tailwind css anywhere, colors are really easy to customize https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors/#app

Comment: Hey @JoelPeltonen, did you find any solution for the same without eject??

Comment: Is it possible to do this without eject?

Comment: @tarunjain I did not, nope

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer was a good clue but it didn't work for me. I spent an hour fixing my Webpack config and I just want to share the result here so no one else wastes their time here.

You should create your function in the `sass-loader`'s `sassOptions` object like below:  (using `node-sass-utils` is not required)

```
// Import node-sass at the top of your config file
const nodeSass = require('node-sass');


// Add this object to the sass-loader options object
sassOptions: {
    functions: {
        "env($variable)": variable => {
            const value = variable.getValue();
            const envValue = process.env[value]
            const sassValue = new nodeSass.types.String(envValue); 
            return sassValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use any env variables in your SASS files like below:

```css
.my-class {
  color: env('ENV_VAR_NAME');
}
```